Is there a way to use the rstac package with Google Earth Engine?
A bit like accessing the planetary computer or the Earth data from NASA, is there a way to access the Google Earth Engine catalogue with rstac (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog for example the DEM from Canada https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NRCan_CDEM)?
How could I use the code below to make it work by changing the stac link and the collections?
library(rstac)
items <- stac("https://cmr.earthdata.nasa.gov/stac/LPCLOUD/") |> 
  stac_search(collections = list("HLSS30_2.0", "HLSL30_2.0"),
              bbox = c(-73.72, 45.55, -73.53, 45.57),
              limit = 100,
              datetime = '2020-07-01T00:00:00Z/2022-09-15T23:59:59Z'
              ) |> 
  post_request()

